# Second Google+ button invisible in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-plus

We have Google+ buttons one of our website. They are showing fine in all browsers except Firefox. The button above the article works fine, but the button below is invisible in Firefox. Can't find why this is the case, does anyone have some ideas on how to fix this?

You can see the problem on the live website at http://www.cyprusexpat.co.uk/article/id:266/insolvency-law-in-cyprus

Comment: I see both of them in Firefox 8.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Firefox 8.0.1 and also the Aurora build is failing on me and showing a blank spot where the bottom +1 button should be. Thanks for testing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the HTML once again I noticed someone added the `script`-tag that you need to insert for the Google Plus button twice. This is not as it should be and Firefox stops rendering Google Plus buttons after the second `script`-tag.

So I removed the duplicate `script`-tag and all browsers, including Firefox, are rendering the buttons fine now!